# Sending text data via USSD in Android

Tags: android, mobile, ussd

Is there a possibility to send text data via USSD in android?

The only way I found was to invoke an android.intent.action.CALL intent and append the text data after as follows

tel:#(short code)*(bookmark)*(number of pages)*(page number)*(MSISDN)*(text data)#
e.g. tel:#161*129*1*1*5555*(text data)#

But once I append text data & start the ACTION_CALL but the text data will be converted into keypad codes.

That is ACL = 225.

Is there any other way to piggy back text data on an USSD call without getting the text converted into keypad codes?

Comment: Hey, have you solved this problem? It seams that only some phone models have this bug/issue. What model do you have? I have Samsung Galaxy Ace 2.3.3 and i cant enter letter in manualy dialing ussd, but when dialing programatically it converts to numbers.

There's an open issue here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13995

Answer (score 0):

OutgoingCallReceiver convert text data using these 2 methods: PhoneNumberUtils.convertKeypadLettersToDigits and PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators
Using ACTION_CALL intent there is no way to prevent it happened.
I hope there is a way to use internal library to send USSD directly, but have no idea how to achieve it...