# calling USSD with text attached on android

Tags: android, uri, ussd

How is it possible to call a USSD with a text attached on android. For example: `*455*1*Hello*0#`. I have looked around the web and couldn't find any solution for it. The only question that seems to resemble what I want to achieve was asked 9 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898171/sending-text-data-via-ussd-in-android). Surely there is some API or a workaround available in Android after all these years?

- I also tried to `URI.encode` all characters that aren't a number. No luck there as explained [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36924762#comment24).
- I have thought of interacting with the dialog to insert the text but that will take a significant amount of time for the user which renders the app useless.
- Neither `ACTION_CALL` intent nor `placeCall` API does anything to solve this.
- Is it not in the protocol to send a text on the initial request?
- `TelephonyManager::sendUssdRequest(String, TelephonyManager.UssdResponseCallback, Handler)` was introduced in API 26. I am targeting API 21 and above. I haven't checked if that solves it yet tho.

Comment: Recommended min API now is 23, I'd recommend switching to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [library](https://github.com/romellfudi/VoIpUSSD) seems to be what you are looking for.

Library is called VoIpUSSD by romellfudi incase link doesn't work.

Comment: I was looking for an API to do this correctly instead of a hacky method like this using accessibility but looks like I don't have any choice. Thanks